# Wordpress signup creating pagenot found coming on form submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have created a function to create a login registration form custom but I do not why when i click on submit for it is showing me 404 not found error i do not know why this is happening

```
unction registration_form( $name, $fname, $email, $password, $familyname, $username,  $password, $gender) {

echo '
<div class="login-form">
<form action="' . get_site_url() . '/sign-up" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? $name : null ) . '">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Father Name" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['fname']) ? $fname : null ) . '">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="familyname" placeholder="Family Name" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['familyname']) ? $familyname : null ) . '">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['email']) ? $email : null ) . '">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['username']) ? $username : null ) . '">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['password'] ) ? $password : null ) . '">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nickname">Gender</label>
    <div><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male</div> 
    <div><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female</div> 
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/>

<div class="form-group"><br>
Already have account with us <a href="'.get_site_url().'/log-in" title="" class="reg" id="">Login Here</a>
</div>

</form>
</div>
';
 }

function complete_registration() {
global $name, $fname, $password, $familyname, $username,  $password, $gender;
if ( 1 > count( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() ) ) {
    $userdata = array(
    'user_login'    =>   $username,
    'user_email'    =>   $email,
    'user_pass'     =>   $password,
    'user_name'     =>   $name,
    'family_name'   =>   $familyname,
    'father_name'   =>   $fname,
    'gender'        =>   $gender
    );
    $user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    echo 'Registration complete. Goto <a href="' . get_site_url() . '/wp-login.php">login page</a>.';   
}
```

}

```
function custom_registration_function() {
if ( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    // sanitize user form input
    $username   =   sanitize_user( $_POST['username'] );
    $password   =   esc_attr( $_POST['password'] );
    $email      =   sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] );
    $name       =   esc_url( $_POST['name'] );
    $fname      =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['fname'] );
    $familyname =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['familyname'] );
    $gender     =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gender'] );

    // call @function complete_registration to create the user
    // only when no WP_error is found
    complete_registration(
        $username,
        $password,
        $email,
        $name,
        $fname,
        $familyname,
        $gender
    );
} else {
     registration_form(
       $username,
        $password,
        $email,
        $name,
        $fname,
        $familyname,
        $gender
    );
}

}

// Register a new shortcode: [cr_custom_registration]
add_shortcode( 'cr_custom_registration', 'custom_registration_shortcode' );

// The callback function that will replace [book]
function custom_registration_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    custom_registration_function();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Above is the code I have created but when I click on submit it shows me 404 not found as it shoudn't be The link given in the action is same so i do not know why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a 404 because your form action is "sign-up" and I assume that you didn't create such an url. You need to create a page template that displays your custom form and assign it to a page which has the "sign-up" slug. Or you can create a virtual page, where you should process your form.

Details on how to create a virtual page in wordpress here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress

Comment: the face is the page on which the form is showing has a slug of sign-up it is showing when page is load but when I click on register it shows 404 not found with same url it is really strange to me

Comment: Do you have it live somewhere so I can check the behavior?

Comment: This is really strange to me as this shouldn't be happened

Comment: There is no 404 for me. If I click the "Register button" the page reloads and I get the "Registration complete. Goto login page." message.

Comment: Totally strange I am seeing 404 when i register when I add information and when i submit without entering any info then 404 is not coming up

Comment: I got it, the problem is that you are using "name" as an input name and wordpress user that term internally. Modify name with something else and it will work.

Comment: Great thanks a lot just a minor thing which was letting me worst but why is not adding my custom fields Array ( [user_login] => test.est [user_email] => test@domainname.com [user_pass] => test123 [user_name] => http://test%20Name [family_name] => family name [father_name] => father name [gender] => Male )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142408/discussion-between-sticksu-and-mark-alan).

Comment: The custom data needs to be saved via https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta or https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta, they will not be saved on wp_insert_user.

Comment: If your problem is solved please mark my answer as correct. Thanks. :)